# Help with understanding logical consequence.

Tags: logic

We've been tasked with figuring out whether Q is a logical consequence  of these three statements

P ⇒ Q and ¬Q ⇒ R and P∨ ¬R

Can anyone shed some light on what exactly is meant by logical consequence?

Comment: See [Logical consequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_consequence).

Comment: What is meant depends very much on your course. Maybe it means, informally, "must be true if those three statements is true". Maybe it means "follows via some truth table method". Maybe it means "follows via some deduction method with rules like modus ponens". Or maybe it means some fourth thing. I didn't downvote, but I can't tell you what it means in your book/course.

Comment: Try by contradiction... Is it possible to define a truth assignment to the prop variables such that the purported conclusion ($Q$) is FALSE and all the premise are **all** TRUE ? If not, you have shown that the conclusion follow logically from the premises.

Comment: So in other words: If Q is true then all the expressions should be either True or false? Or Q determines the outcome of each expression?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [Logical consequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_consequence) for the definition.

Regarding [propositional logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tautology_(logic)#Tautological_implication), the definition amounts to :

> "every [valuation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valuation_(logic)) (or tuth assignment) that causes all the premises to be true also assign true to the conclusion".

Equivalently :

> "there is no tuth assignment that causes all the premises to be true and the conclusion to be false".

We can use the second definition reasoning by contradiction, i.e. trying to find a truth assignment $v$ for the propositional variables such that the purported conclusion ($Q$) is FALSE and the premise are all TRUE.

Thus, we start with $v(Q)=\text F$.

In order to satisfy the first premise : $P \to Q$, having $v(Q)=\text F$, we are forced to set $v(P)=\text F$.

In order to satisfy the third premise : $P \lor ¬R$, having $v(P)=\text F$, we are forced to set $v(R)=\text F$.

Now, we have $v(Q)=\text F$ and $v(R)=\text F$, that implies : $v(¬Q \to R)= v(\text T \to \text F)=\text F$.

*Conclusion* : we have shown that it is impossible to find a tuth assignment that causes all the premises to be true and the conclusion to be false.